# FancyBox with PartialView in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fancybox, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm wondering if anyone has an idea for how to use FancyBox in an MVC3 site to load a partial view (as a popup). FancyBox works fine for me when loading a full view, but breaks if the controller method returns a partial view.

1. I've followed all the instructions on the fancybox site.
2. customizations:

   ```
   $("a.myclass").fancybox({
    ...
    'type': ajax
   });
   ```
3. the link

   ```
   @Html.ActionLink("My Popup", "MyActionName", new {@class = "myclass"} )
   ```

Any idea why this will work with a full view, and not a partial?

Thanks!!

Comment: I would also like to know. Did you find the answer? I am trying to show a google map in a popup window. My first idea was to use Layout=null, but I am using Orchard CMS and that is not supported. Maybe it will help you though.

Answer (score 2):

1. Bind `FancyBox` to class and specify ajax--like I did here:

   ```
   $(".emailViewFancybox").fancybox(
   {                
       type: 'ajax',
       transitionIn: 'none',
       transitionOut: 'none'
   });
   ```
2. Give whatever you want to trigger this an href attribute containing the URL.  Use `@Url.Content` like so: `@Url.Content("~/MyController/MyPartialViewName")`
3. Make sure your `ActionResult` return value is `PartialView`:

   ```
   return PartialView("MyPartialViewName", myObjectModel);
   ```
4. This will need a route in `Global.asax`.